# Read nested widget/class properties value in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, key

I'm building a simple app with lots of nested widgets/classes from different specialised files

list of files:

> main.dart                -> the menu file used to start the activity
> "Activity()"
>
> group_widgets.dart       -> the file that contains the custom widget
> "CustomWidget()"
>
> file_a.dart              -> the file that uses the custom widgets
> inside the "Activity()"
>
> other.dart -> other files that needs to manage data changed in CustomWidget()

> inside main.dart:

```
onPressed: () {
 Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
   builder: (context) => const Activity(),
 ));
},
```

> inside group_widgets.dart:

```
class CustomWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomWidget> createState() => _CustomWidgetState();
}

class _CustomWidgetState extends State<CustomWidget> {
  var _boolean = false;
  bool switchBoolean(bool state) => !state;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () => {
        setState(() {
          _boolean = switchBoolean(_boolean);
        })
      },
      child: Container(
        color: _boolean == true ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> inside file_a.dart

```
class Activity extends StatefulWidget {
  const Activity({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Activity> createState() => _ActivityState();
}

class _ActivityState extends State<Activity> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    bool boolean = true;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: const [
            CustomWidget(),
            Text('Here where to show the variable from CustomWidget'
                'and prove I can retrieve it')
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> inside other.dart

```
if ( booleanFromCustomWidget == true) {
  Something ...
}
```

What is the best practice to achieve it?
I've read a lot here but nothing seems to well fit my needing.

Just comment if my request is not as clear as it seems to me))

Comment: Check out my answer, if I am right with my assumption, you pretty much can delete the code and write a view lines of text to convey the meaning :)

Answer (score 1):

Please correct me if I am wrong, but if you want to access data from parent widgets from inside their descendants (children or even nested children) you can either pass them down via parameter arguments:

```
 Child(int age, String name);
```

And then accept it in the new file, where the `Child` widget lives, via its constructor:

```
class Child {
  String name;
  int age;
     
  // Constructor
  Child(String passedName, int passedAge) {
    this.name = passedName;
    this.age = passedAge;
  }
}
```

Inside the parent.dart you then have to import the children.dart to use it.

Or use a popular package like the provider package: https://pub.dev/packages/provider
This allows you to store data containers, which you can access basically anywhere in your code. Feel free to google it & watch some tutorials to get started, as it is the preferred approach to avoid passing data to widget which really do not care about the passed parameters.

Note: You can transfer the idea to output the String data like in your example code above.

Comment: Sorry, but it seems to not fit my needings, what I need to do is just watch for a status of a switch that works autonomously in another class, then make some external logic work after that.
But probably "provider" would work, I have to find out better ))

Comment: Yeah that sounds like a good use case for provider - in the end it is just a statemanagement solution (is something toggled / switched for example) - but for getting a suitable answer you have to be more precise in your question ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a state manager like provider, or bloc
At the top level, you set up the data services

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).